# nodejs - sails.js lock query (transactions)

Tags: node.js, locking, sails.js, waterline

**The case:**

I'm creating an api with SAILS.js, sails.js uses [waterline](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline) for ORM. The api returns lets say photographs, many users are able to vote for a picture. The pictures will be ordered on number of votes.

**Procedure**:
When a user votes for a song, I've to check the number of votes ("SELECT"|| picture.findById()) AND after that I have to increment that number by one ("UPDATE" picture.update).

**Problem**:
[transaction](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-transactions-with-different-apis.html)/ locking in Sails.js, these two queries should be excecuted without having a other query modifying the picture data within the select and update query of our vote system.

How should we perform locking/ transition in sails.js (node js framework)

THANKS

Answer (score 0):

Sails [does](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/datastores/transaction) support transactions.

Here is an example of a transaction in sails.js:

```
await sails.getDatastore().transaction(async db=> {

  await Model
    .create({foo: bar})
    .usingConnection(db);

  if (somethingWentWrong) {
    throw 'error happened - transaction rollback';
  }

  await Model
    .update({id: 1}))
    .set({votes: 1})
    .usingConnection(db);

}).intercept('Error', () => res.serverError());
```